# Bone Problem (not bending) - Following Animated Book Tutorial

Tags: rigging, bones

I'm following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDK9i9T8bwM

And one of my bones looks completely straight, but it should bend

[image: straight bone]

On the other side both bones look ok, the only difference I've noticed is the connected checkbox

This is how it looks for the bone that is not working

[image: settings for straight bone]

and this is how it looks for the bone that works correctly

[image: bone deforming correctly]

I'm lost, I see the parenting the same for both, same constraints, same number of segments. I checked the lattices and they are called the same, and it looks like the vertex points were defined correctly as well.

What else could it be?

Comment: if your bone is not connected, maybe come back to Edit mode and connect it... hard to tell without the file:  blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: @moonboots thanks for your reply, I think the bone is parented. Here's the file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fohehVW3mlU6ndYqoE35a9VTKmEP7ChI

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I had to select DEF_pages_top.R then hold SHIFT click on the Armature and then CONTROL+P to connect it. That gave me the deformation I was looking for.

Thanks @moonbots for your reply!